# ORACLE Convert String to date without known format

Tags: string, oracle, date

We have an incoming file that has a field which is a string that holds a date value. The string(date value) can be any number of formats. We need to first convert the value to a date such that we can then format that date the way we need it.

In SQL Server we can:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('stringvalue' as date),'yyyyMM') AS MyDate
```

This works in almost all the test cases we have tried with different types of date formatting.

However, it ORACLE it appears you need to first know the Date Format of the StringValue before you can successfully convert it.

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('stringvalue','MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYYMM') AS dt 
from dual;
```

Is there any way in ORACLE we can do this without knowing the 'MM/DD/YYYY' piece above??

Comment: What does SQL Server return for '011001' ? 10/Jan, or 01/Oct? Oracle also has Cast() function and it uses your session NLS_DATE_FORMAT by default.

Comment: As I mentioned in SQL it works for all the test case we have tried. Those test cases did have some assumptions and that was there would be in the string value a representation of at least a month and a year (e.g. MMMYYY worked, m/d/yy worked, however MMMYY does not work). 
We just tried the same SQL in ORACLE and received error. SELECT to_char(CAST('1/1/2022' as date),'YYYYMM') AS MyDate
FROM DUAL

Comment: Did you set nls_date_format to the same value as DATEFORMAT in ms sql server client?

Comment: we have not touched, in either SQL or ORACLe any nls_date formats. In SQL we just typed in the CAST Function and executed. We did 14 different formats and since these 14 worked these will be our acceptable formats. The one we tried that did not work was in the format "MMMYY" so this will be on our not allowed list. "MMMYYYY" did work and is on our allowed list.....we would like to do the same with ORACLE - but again ORACLE is requiring us to know which format, of the allowed, is being used by our customer in order to convert the string to a date successully.

Comment: Can you require your source clean up their act and send dates in a format you dictate or at least in ONE format?  This usually happens when a user-entered field has no validation.  Push back a little, it's for their own good.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get dates in different masks, there is no way to do that. If you want to avoid the mask, there is only one way to do that, but it would affect all the statements in that session. You might specify the session level nls_date_format, then using CAST you don't need to specify any mask

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd/mm/yyyy' ;

Session altered.

SQL> select cast('10/01/2020' as date) from dual ;

CAST('10/0
----------
10/01/2020
```

However, it won't accept any other mask, because assume the default one

```
SQL> select cast('2020/01/10' as date) from dual ;
select cast('2020/01/10' as date) from dual
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

But that happens too in SQL Server. What the SQL SERVER function FORMAT(CAST string as date) mask ) is more or less doing the same but in inverted order.

- cast converts the mask to a date ( using the default SET DATEFORMAT )
- format converts the date to a string based on the format you want.

Let me show with an example

```
SELECT CAST('03/11/2020' AS date); 

2020-03-11
```

It returns 3th of November, when in my case I meant 11th of March. Why  ? because also SQL Server relays in the SET DATEFORMAT to change the session level settings for the formatting of the dates.

There is no computational language that can do that. The mask has to be provided , either implicit or explicitly. SQL , like any other language, can't understand what I meant by 3/11 ( either 3 of november of 11 of March, both are ok ).

Comment: We can't change the session. We can require certain formats that we know works and disallow those that do not work - in the SQL scenario. Because the SQL CAST function is not requiring a Format property. In ORACLE even if we require certain formats, we still need, Format property because the to_date function is requiring it. Without providing it we get errors.

Comment: if you have specific formats, you can always build a function to treat them. But you can't expect that neither Oracle or SQL Server can understand what 11/3/2020 means without a proper mask format

Comment: Yep, we have come to the same conclusion. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You could try profiling your text values, to see what kind of date formats you have.

A sample query to do something like that would look like this:

```
WITH subq AS (
   SELECT
      txt_date_value,
      REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(txt_date_value, '[a-zA-Z]', 'A'), '\d', 'd') AS reg_reduced
   FROM data_table
   )
SELECT 
   reg_reduced, 
   COUNT(1), 
   MIN(txt_date_value), 
   MAX(txt_date_value)
FROM subq
GROUP BY reg_reduced
ORDER BY 1
;
```

Once you have your list of (most likely) date formats, you can put them all into a stored function (as properly formatted regex, of course) to convert to date, based on those formats:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION text_to_date(p_date_str IN VARCHAR2) RETURN DATE
IS
    v_format VARCHAR2(15) := 'OTHER';
BEGIN
    v_format := 
        CASE
            WHEN REGEXP_LIKE (p_date_str, '\d{4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}')
                THEN
                 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            WHEN REGEXP_LIKE (p_date_str, '\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{4}')
                THEN
                 'mm-dd-yyyy'
            WHEN REGEXP_LIKE (p_date_str, '\d{1,2} [A-Za-z]{3} \d{4}')
                THEN
                 'dd MON yyyy'
            ELSE
             'OTHER'
        END;
    IF v_format = 'OTHER' THEN 
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSE
        RETURN to_date(p_date_str, v_format);
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN NULL;
END;
```

Add to the v_format CASE statement as necessary.